# Containing equal objects in the HashSet

Tags: java, collections

Hello I found a question like this related to collections.

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(!(o instanceof Person))return false;
        Person p=(Person)o;
        return p.name.equals(this.name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Person> hs=new HashSet<Person>();
        hs.add(new Person("Hi"));
        hs.add(new Person("Hi"));
        hs.add(new Person("Hi"));
        hs.add(new Person("Hi"));

        System.out.println("Elements"+hs.size());
    }
}
```

The size of the Hashset is given as 4. But doesn't it need to be 1? Since the equals method has implemented, can the HashSet contain multiple Person objects with the same name?

Do all the Person objects have the same hashcode as the hashCode method is not overridden?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.equals()` is not enough. You need [`.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--).

When you implement one, as a rule of thumb, always implement the other!

And obey the contract; in particular, two instances of a same class which are `.equals()` must have the same `.hashCode()`.

---

Now, a `HashSet`, as its name implies, relies on... Hashes. And in this case, on the result of `.hashCode()`. Depending on the result, it will insert the object you add into a different hash bucket.

And as your objects all have different hash codes, they end up in four different buckets...

Comment: Thanks.. If the .hashCode() is not implemented , what determines the Hash Values to have different values of the objects in this case? When we just add, hs.add(4); for twice the size of the hastSet shows as 1. How this differentiates from the previous case?

Comment: @Hiru Short answer, the [`Object.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) says in part *This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer*.

Comment: If you want to see the default hashcode of an object x, you can call System.identityHashCode(x). When you add hs.add(4), you are adding number 4 which has always hashcode 4 (equal to its value). In case of Person, you are creating new Person objects, each time having a different address in memory and hence different hash code

Comment: Oki thanks. I have another question. If a HashSet contains more than one Person object with name- "Fred", then removing another Person, also with name "Fred" will remove them all. How this becomes wrong?

Comment: @Hiru you are wrong in the sense that the second "Fred" will never be added in the first place; a set discards duplicates. Provided you have coded `equals()/hashCode()` correctly when you use a `HashSet`, that is ;)